# Page Controller Carousel

Tags: flutter

I would like to add a carousel to my page, when i scroll a new page is fetched from API.
When i reload the data list i am showing, the page controller wont navigate at this page.
However it navigates to the required page on start.
when i use jumpToPage it navigates but with a flicker, any idea how to remove it ??

```
Widget _buildCarousel(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: bloc.getUserMeetingsResponse,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<MeetingModel>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        pc = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8 , initialPage: UserUtil.getUserRole(AppSharedData().userID)  == UserRole.student ? 0: bloc.getDesiredPage());
        Widget view = new Container(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                // you may want to use an aspect ratio here for tablet support
                height: Dimension.cardHeightRegular ,
                child: new PageView.builder(
                  // store this controller in a State to save the carousel scroll position
                  controller: pc,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
                    return HorizontalCarouselClassCell(meetingModel: snapshot.data[itemIndex]);
                  },
                  onPageChanged: (pageNumber) {
                    bloc.pageChanged(pageNumber);
                  },
                  reverse: false,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
        if(!bloc.isAddOnList){
          Future((){
            pc.jumpToPage(bloc.getDesiredPage());
          });
        }
        return view;

      }
      else if (snapshot.hasError){
        print("Error Received");

      }
      return Container();
    },
  );
}
```